# JAVA Apache POI wrong document write output

Tags: java, apache-poi

I'm reading a file, adding some data to paragraphs, and then writing out a document another file.

The problem I'm facing is that the output file is unreadable, I can't open it, and if a binary open it I can see that it don't have the correct format.

Every character has a `?` character at the left side.

Can you give me some advice about what is happening?
[Wrong output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ucuQj.png)
[Correct output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T8ncZ.png)

EDIT: Code Save function

```
 FileOutputStream out = null;
try {
    // Add true to make the data append possible in output stream.
    out = new FileOutputStream(filePath, true);
    doc.write(out);
    out.flush();
} catch (Exception ex) {
    ex.printStackTrace();
} finally {
    out.close();
}
```

Edit file:

```
File file = new File("muestra.doc");
FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(file.getAbsolutePath());
POIFSFileSystem fs = new POIFSFileSystem(fis);
HWPFDocument document = new HWPFDocument(fs);
Range range = document.getRange();
for (int i = 0; i < document.getParagraphTable().getParagraphs().size(); i++) {
    Paragraph p = range.getParagraph(i);
    p.insertBefore("£");
 }
```

Comment: Looks like using the pound character has caused POI to write out your file in Unicode.  Maybe the software you are reading it with is too old to understand that?

Comment: There is no problem because writing some arbitrary character produces the same output

Comment: That FileOutputStream constructor with append=true - that looks strange, you can't just append one DOC file at the end of another DOC file.

Comment: I delete the file every time, I know I could put false but that's not the point, the problem are the "?" characters apearing at the left of every other charcter.